QML Combobox mouse right button click handling
I tried to customize Combobox but I can not handle right button click. How can I realized any button click handling? Log 'Qt.RightButton clicked!' never show.
    ComboBox {
        id: root
        padding: Sizes.comboboxPadding
        focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
    
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                console.log("clicked! mouse.button:", mouse.button)
                 if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
                     console.log("Qt.RightButton clicked!")
                     popup.open()
                 }
            }
        }
...


Per default, MouseArea only accepts left button clicks. Add
acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

to your MouseArea object and it should work.
Similar question here.
